# Get correct details when using MAX() function in mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

So I have two mySQL tables:  `products` and `prices`. In products I have the informations about the product (id, name, type, date,...)  and prices include informations for the prices for a products. i.E. product USB with ID CF003X from table **products** is available in table**prices** with sellers (A, B, C and prices 18.00, 12.00, 13.50).

Now, when I want to select the highest price for a date, groupped by product IDs, the query returns the highest prices, but doesnt show correctly from which seller.

I also want to get results where i.E. seller 'Asus' had the highest price1

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8fb/6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example where subqueries can be used: create a subquery that returns the highest price for product in a certain data range, then join this back to the prices table and get the supplier(s) who supply at that price. The date range, however, should probably be in the prices table, not in the products one. Prices change, products not really (they can be flagged as not to be listed). You should also consider having a product and a pricing id in the pricing table.

However, I'm going along with the fields you supplied within the sqlfiddle example.

```
select prod.id, p.seller, p.price1, p.price2
from prices p
inner join (select id, max(price1) as maxprice from prices group by id) mp on p.id=mp.id and p.price1=mp.maxprice
inner join products prod on p.id=prod.id
where prod.date='...'
```

You can extend the above query to show a specific vendor only by adding that vendor to the where criteria.

Comment: Works great. But I have a subquestion. What to do if you have a million of database data? It will load unendless.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on a lot of factors. If you have this scenario, then I suggest you ask it in a separate question, but only if it's an actual problem, not a theoretical one. On theoretical level this is too broad.